# Python file logging. Unable to log under uWsgi

Tags: python, flask, logging, uwsgi

I am running my Flask application under uWsgi using Python logging fileConfig.
The problem is I am not able to log into the file nor to the console. The app creates the log file but it is always empty.
The logging worked when I ran the service in the debug mode without uWsgi.

My project structure:

```
project/
├── src/
│   └── app.py
├── logging.conf
├── wsgi.py
└── uwsgi.ini
```

app.py content:

```
import logging
from logging.config import fileConfig

from flask import Flask

fileConfig('logging.conf', disable_existing_loggers=False)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    logger.info("Got request")
    return "<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0')
```

wsgi.py content:

```
from src.app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Logging configuration (logging.conf):

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=timedRotatingFileHandler,consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=timedRotatingFileHandler,consoleHandler

[handler_timedRotatingFileHandler]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=("/Users/user/project/logs/project.log", 'MIDNIGHT', 1)

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

uwsgi.ini content:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

socket = 0.0.0.0:5000
protocol = http
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

And I run all of this stuff as follows:

```
uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
```

Here is uWsgi logs:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.18 (64bit) on [Thu Apr  9 14:45:08 2020] ***
compiled with version: 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29) on 07 April 2020 07:23:53
os: Darwin-19.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.3.0: Thu Jan  9 20:58:23 PST 2020; root:xnu-6153.81.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64
nodename: User-MacBook-Pro.local
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 4
current working directory: /Users/user/project
detected binary path: /Users/user/project/venv/bin/uwsgi
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 2784
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 10240
lock engine: OSX spinlocks
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 0.0.0.0:5000 fd 3
Python version: 3.6.7 (v3.6.7:6ec5cf24b7, Oct 20 2018, 03:02:14)  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x7fbc6080aa00
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72888 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0x7fbc6080aa00 pid: 9587 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 9587, cores: 1)
[pid: 9587|app: 0|req: 1/1] 127.0.0.1 () {42 vars in 1087 bytes} [Thu Apr  9 14:45:26 2020] GET / => generated 40 bytes in 10 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 79 bytes (2 switches on core 0)
```

What can I try to force my application to log as defined in the logging settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was everything ok in the configuration. I just missed the logging line in `hello()`. 
Maybe the config could be useful to someone in the future.